# Tumblr theme -> vertical lines color

Tags: css, colors, tumblr

I'm currently editing a tumblr theme and I'd like to change the color of the vertical strips which bind the comments of the reblogs between them.

Here's the code of my tumblr :
http://pastebin.com/RFARBNj1

And here is my Tumblr in case you want to make sure of what I'm talking about :
zwizzor dot tumblr dot com

And a screenshot of the precise thing I want to modify :
http://gyazo.com/02eaca22dc68171319835126e6221b9a

A great thank you in advance !

BTW if you have a way to change the posts background color without including all the main.css it'd be great too :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out myself, it was this property :

> .post blockquote {
>
> > border-left: 3px solid #eee;}